# Merge 2 sheets, always keeping the value from sheet 1 if there are duplicates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 Excel sheets that I'd like to merge. They are an inventory file and are roughly 5,500 rows each, with each row being a product and each column being an attribute. The first column is the unique identifier.

One copy was taken a few weeks ago to make some updates on various attributes of items. During that time several new products were added so the old file is out of date.

I'd like to merge them by using the new sheet as the primary, and updating this sheet by finding any duplicates between the new sheet and the old sheet, then replacing the duplicate with the value from the old sheet.

For one column this would be possible with a VLOOKUP but I'm not sure how to tackle it for an entire sheet. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to use a function or can you use a macro?

Comment: Macro works, although I'm on Office '11 (Mac) so i don't know if there would be some limitations?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `copy` has the current information about products that existed when `copy` was created (although not necessarily all products were updated), and `primary` has stale information about those products, plus some new products.

If this is so, then it seems `copy` could serve as the new basis for `primary`. In other words, you want to start with `copy` and just add the new rows from `primary`, right?

Using `VLOOKUP`:

1. apply `VLOOKUP` on `primary`, searching for matching products on `copy`
2. filter this column to show `#N/A` (or sort on this column so the `#N/As` bunch up to one end)
3. copy the `#N/A` rows to `copy`
4. blank the `VLOOKUP` column on `copy`
5. be sure to remember `copy` now has the current information